# Split column into different rows on SQLite recursively using delimiter ","

Tags: sqlite, recursion, delimiter, substr

I have a SQLite table just like this:

[image: table_name: surat]

the table name is 'surat'

But i want to make id_ayat to be split into different rows using SQLite query, and expected result just like this:

```
  _id|id_surat|id_ayat
  ---+--------+-------
  3  |   2    |  112
  3  |   2    |  213
  3  |   3    |  19
  3  |   3    |  83
  3  |   3    |  85
  3  |   3    |  102
```

is that possible? what query that i can use in SQLite format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a recursive `CTE`:

```
with recursive cte as (
  select _id, id_surat, id_ayat, 
    id_ayat + 0 col 
  from tablename 
  union all 
  select _id, id_surat, trim(substr(id_ayat, length(col) + 2)), 
    trim(substr(id_ayat, length(col) + 2)) + 0 
  from cte  
  where instr(id_ayat, ',')
)
select _id, id_surat, col id_ayat 
from cte
order by _id, id_surat
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fWAgM818nX5QL4MEGTW8js/0).
Results:

```
| _id | id_surat | id_ayat |
| --- | -------- | ------- |
| 3   | 2        | 112     |
| 3   | 2        | 213     |
| 3   | 3        | 19      |
| 3   | 3        | 83      |
| 3   | 3        | 85      |
| 3   | 3        | 102     |
```

Comment: what does + 0 means? after i tested that query, i got 0,0,0 result on the first row, but on the next rows, i got the expected result, thanks... but, i still confused why the first row 0,0,0... :-/

Comment: I don't know what your actual data is. You can see in the demo that for the sample data that you posted this code works.

Comment: `+0` converts a text value like `100,200,300` to the number 100.